# Existing Algorithms for label placement with callouts

Tags: pyqgis, labeling, algorithm, callout

I am thinking to answer the question here: [Label placement with callouts in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/470903/label-placement-with-callouts-in-qgis/471015#471015).

I want to implement a kind of algorithm in python that will create 2 different columns [X and Y] that will be the position where the labels will be placed. In this algorithm the following things have to be considered:

1. The callout lines can't cross each other.
2. The labels don't overlap the geometry (polygon) at a scale of 1:XXXX.
3. Labels don't intersect.
4. An optional minimum distance between the labels and the polygon.

Does anyone know of existing algorithms (in scientific papers, GitHub) that I can base my algorithm on?